# Can I transfer an SD used on a B+ to an A?

Tags: raspbian, sd-card

I have a model B+ Raspberry Pi which has raspbian installed on the SD card. If I get a model A or A+, can I simply swap the SD card over and the Pi will run raspbian like it did before? Or because it is a previous version will the SD not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do it without a problem as long as you didn't do any B+ specific settings.

Comment: Thanks, can you give me an example of a B+ specific setting?

Comment: For example, settings for the 40 pin GPIO found on the B+.

Comment: B+ to A+ should be the same GPIO configuration, no?